# Where is Apple Watch music stored?

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch

How do I access music files (m4a) stored on the Apple Watch, which are downloaded from an Apple Music Subscription using the Watch app with Swift?

Which directory are the music files stored in? I'm using this location:
`let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!`
I search for m4a files in this directory which gives back no m4a files.

I have also tried this directory:
`let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .musicDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!` This also gives back no m4a files.

I think maybe the music file extension on the apple watch might be different such as mp3, but that doesn't seem probable. I'm most probably searching in the wrong directory on the Apple Watch.

Can someone tell me whether I'm searching in the correct directory?